# Unable to access args value in python

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have a class Team, I want to write a Unit test for it,
class name team.py

```
class Team()
    def __init__(self, args):
        if args.player:
            self.player_name = args.player
        self.sports = ''

def test__init__(self):
    test1 = team.Team(player="deepak")
```

While executing this, I am getting error like:

> AttributeError: "'str' object has no attribute 'player'"

I know it is very basic but right not I need some quick help to use this. I am not aware how to access this while creating object in test file.

Comment: I'd recommend starting with e.g. https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/classes.html (and [tag:python-3.x]); that's not how keyword arguments work.

Comment: `def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs): if kwargs['player']...`

Comment: @TenaciousB `kwargs` is a *dictionary*, you access members by key not attribute.

Comment: The argument to `Team()` is supposed to be an instance of a class with a `player` attribute. It's not supposed to be a string.

Comment: Thanks but  this is the code for which I need to write right now, I cant change anything into the team.py, please suggest how can I access using test1 = team.Team(" what should I mention here "),

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Arguments and keyword arguments don't work like that in python. The closest to what you want would be to use kwargs to get a dict of params.

```
class Team():
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        if kwargs["player"]:
            self.player_name = kwargs["player"]
        self.sports = ""

test1 = Team(player="deepak")
```

See https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/classes.html for some good docs on how python classes work.

EDIT

Since you can't edit the code, you need to have args be an object with the member player.

```
from collections import namedtuple

class Team():
    def __init__(self, args):
        if args.player:
            self.player_name = args.player
        self.sports = ""

TeamArguments = namedtuple("TeamArguments", ["player"])
test1 = Team(TeamArguments(player="deepak"))
```

Comment: Sure, Thanks I know this **kwargs, but I was not aware of  def __init__(self, args) that is why I need help, I cant modify the Team.py. I just want to access this using test file object :)

Comment: @Deepak Mourya do you mean `def __init__(self, *args)` with the "`*`"? If you're passing `args.player` in `def __init__(self, args)` then the object you are passing into `args` needs to be an object with the member `player`

Comment: @Kirk  hmm no, this is def __init__(self, args): no * actually, i am just curious to know or struct right now to access this via here,  test1 = team.Team(" what should I mention here "),

Comment: @Kirk  yea it seems good, just one question if we need to add more attributes like player how can we add more into this, TeamArguments = namedtuple("TeamArguments", ["player"])
Like let's  say player="deepak", hobby="tennis" etc.

Comment: test = Teaam(TeamArguements(player="deepak", hobby="tennis", , ) // like for other args attribute

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.namedtuple